# Do I need to delete all the children of a DOM element , when I delete the parent itself?

Tags: javascript

If I delete a parent element, do the child elements remain in the browser's memory?

```
<div id="parent">
    <ul>
        <li>one</li>
        <li>two</li>
        <li>one</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script>

    var element = document.getElementById("parent"); 
    element.parent.removeChild(element);

</script>
```

Comment: no, garbage collector takes care of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they don't, don't worry. :)

Answer (score 0):

If the children stays in the memory that'd be a very major flaw and a huge memory leak in the browsers code.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you mean `parentNode` there :). `parent` is for accessing a parent frameset or `window` I believe.

It won't remain in memory if removed. Otherwise a lot of memory would be leaking with objects in the DOM with no pointer to them.

Answer (score 0):

The child nodes are removed and taken care of they don't stay back in memory..

Alternative to your code you can use...jQuery

```
$('#parent').empty().remove();
```